# Haskell Applicative [] why can I not replace pure[] with [] in function?

Tags: haskell, applicative

```
ghci> :t pure []
pure [] :: Applicative f => f [a]
```

---

```
ghci> pure []
[]
```

---

```
ghci> :t []
[] :: [a]
```

---

```
ghci> fmap ((:) 2) (pure [])
[2]
```

---

```
ghci> fmap ((:) 2) ([])
[]
```

I would have thought replacing `pure[]` with `[]` in `fmap ((:) 2) (pure [])` would result in the same outcome.. who can explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 15):

The type of `pure` is `Applicative f => a -> f a` so `pure []`

has type `Applicative f => f [a]`. You can specify `f` explicitly for different applicative types e.g.

```
pure [] :: Maybe [String]   //Just []
pure [] :: IO [String]      //displays '[]' in ghci
pure [] :: [[String]]       //[[]]
```

The type of `fmap ((:) 2) (pure [])` is `(Applicative f, Num a) => f [a]`. Since Ghci runs in the IO monad, which is an `Applicative`, it chooses `f` to be `IO`, and displays the resulting list `[2]` which is what you see.

You can specify the applicative type directly to see a different result e.g.

```
fmap ((:) 2) (pure []) :: (Maybe [Int])
```

which is `Just [2]`

In `fmap ((:) 2) ([])`, there are no elements in the input list so you get an empty list.

Comment: fmap ((:) 2) (pure []) :: (IO [Int])
[2]. I did not realize GHCI choosed IO as f for me. You made that clearer.

Comment: fmap ((:) 2) (pure []) :: (IO [Int])  so, it is the same as
fmap ((:) 2) (return []) whicht results in [2]

Answer (score 5):

Why *would* it be the same? They're different expressions.

Perhaps it simplifies things if we just look at lists. So, there's the empty list `[]`. Its type can be anything with brackets around it, in particular also a nested list:

> Prelude> [] :: [[Int]]
>   []

But there's also another "empty nested list":

> Prelude> [[]] :: [[Int]]
>   [[]]

This one isn't really empty though, it merely *contains* only the empty list. (`[[],[],[],...]` would also be possible). In fact, that would be the result of what you've tried, if done in the list applicative:

> Prelude Control.Applicative> pure [] :: [[Int]]
>   [[]]

It is certainly not the same as the empty list,

> Prelude> [[]] == []
>   False

In particular,

> Prelude> (length [], length [[]])
>   (0,1)

And `fmap`pming over an empty list never does anything, while `fmap`ping over an empty-containing list will call the function with `[]`: an easy way to see this is

> Prelude Control.Applicative> fmap undefined []
>   []
>   Prelude Control.Applicative> fmap undefined [[]]
>   [*** Exception: Prelude.undefined

The real confusing thing about your trials is that ghci silently uses the `IO` monad.

---

There's also a subclass of `Applicative` for actual emptiness:

> Prelude Control.Applicative> :i Alternative
>   class Applicative f => Alternative f where
>     empty :: f a
>     (<‌|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
>     some :: f a -> f [a]
>     many :: f a -> f [a]
>       -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
>   instance Alternative [] -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'
>   instance Alternative Maybe -- Defined in `Control.Applicative'

Comment: thnxs, I was indeed  confused by the silent use of IO